# Returning value from query based on results

Tags: mysql

I have this query I'm trying to build to display specific information for a stored table. I'm needing the query to also display the Enemy Guild Name but I'm having trouble getting the query to take the Enemy Guild ID and link it to the name.

```
SELECT g.wPos as wPos, g.szGuildName as szGuildName, g.dwGuildExpWeek as dwGuildExpWeek, g.dwEnemyGuildID as dwEnemyGuildID, gm.wPower as wPower, gd.szName as szName
FROM guild as g
LEFT JOIN guild_member AS gm ON gm.dwGuildID = g.dwGuildID AND gm.wPower = '1'
LEFT JOIN gamedata AS gd ON gd.dwID = gm.dwRoleID
WHERE g.wPos = '1'
```

The output of the query right now results in the following:
[Query Results Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpGew.png)

What I need it to do now is take the dwEnemyGuildID it finds and then use that ID to search for the szGuildName while also displaying the other data it finds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the concept of `SELF JOIN`, in which we will join same table again if we have a field which is a reference to the same table. Here `dwEnemyGuildID` is reference to the same table.

A trivial example of the same is finding Manager for an employee from `employees` table.

Reference: [Find the employee id, name along with their manager_id and name](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql-exercises/join-exercises/write-a-query-to-find-the-employee-id-name-along-with-their-manager_id-manager-name.php)

```
SELECT 
    g.wPos as wPos, 
    g.szGuildName as szGuildName, 
    g.dwGuildExpWeek as dwGuildExpWeek, 
    g.dwEnemyGuildID as dwEnemyGuildID, 
    enemy_g.szGuildName as szEnemyGuildName,  -- pick name from self joined table
    gm.wPower as wPower, 
    gd.szName as szName
FROM guild as g
LEFT JOIN guild_member AS gm ON gm.dwGuildID = g.dwGuildID AND gm.wPower = '1'
LEFT JOIN guild AS enemy_g ON g.dwEnemyGuildID = enemy_g.dwGuildID   -- Use self join
LEFT JOIN gamedata AS gd ON gd.dwID = gm.dwRoleID
WHERE g.wPos = '1';
```

Comment: Thanks for that it does help a lot, I actually found a way to do it just using 3 separate queries but that is insightful.